# Pandas: Creating a new column for if another column is blank or not

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create new columns in a dateframe that will indicate blank or not blank for the rest of the columns. I think this should be fairly simple, but I'm having trouble getting the code quite right...

```
for column, row in df.iterrows():
if(pd.isnull(row[column])):
    df[column + 'Blank or Not'] = "blank"
else:
    df[column + 'Blank or Not'] = "not blank"
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

When I changed it to below:

```
for column, row in df.iterrows():
    if(pd.isnull(row[column])):
        df[str(column) + 'Blank or Not'] = "blank"
    else:
        df[str(column) + 'Blank or Not'] = "not blank"
```

This is the error:

```
 IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Comment: Are you doing this for every column or just one?

Comment: Can you try my edit `df.isnull().applymap({True: 'Blank', False: 'Not Blank'}.get)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the column names are int, so use:

```
if(pd.isnull(row[column])):
    df[str(column) + 'Blank or Not'] = "blank"
else:
    df[str(column) + 'Blank or Not'] = "not blank"
```

---

or in python 3 you can use f-strings:

```
f"{column}Blank or Not"
```

---

Edit: I think you're wanting to do something slightly different:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
    0  1
0 NaN  1

In [22]: df.isnull().applymap({True: 'Blank', False: 'Not Blank'}.get)
Out[22]:
       0          1
0  Blank  Not Blank
```

Comment: @MadelineKinnaird I think you want to do for `column in df.columns` instead of iterrows.